# OpenCV Draw rectangle from center x,y

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to draw a rectangle using only a point to the center. So pretty much a rectangle around my center point. What is the easiest way of doing this?Thanks.

Comment: `cv::rectangle( image, cvPoint(x-w/2,y-h/2),cvPoint(x+w/2,y+h/2/2),CV_RGB(r,g,b), 1, 8);`

Comment: Thanks William, could you post this again so i can accept it as an answer , and another quick question how do i convert this to a CvRect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that *center=(x,y)*, then:

```
cv::rectangle( image, 
               cvPoint(x-w/2,y-h/2),
               cvPoint(x+w/2,y+h/2),
               CV_RGB(r,g,b), 1, 8
             );
```

`CvRect` stores the top-left point as reference. So:

```
CvRect myrect=cvRect(x-w/2,y-h/2,w,h);
```

Comment: Why `y+h/2/2` on the 3rd line?

Comment: maybe a typo? dont really remember. try it and fix it! :)

Comment: Fixed! Bottom point should be center + height / 2 not center + height / 4