# How to draw a square in an image from its center (x,y) in opencv Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I want to draw a `square box (not filled, just line around)` in an image from a given `center (x,y)`. I can see a similar opencv implementation in C++. Such as this.. [OpenCV Draw rectangle from center x,y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785602/opencv-draw-rectangle-from-center-x-y)
How do I do this in Python?
I can draw it for a circle from a center.. not for a square box.

```
im = cv2.imread("path_to_/img.png")
cv2.circle(im, (270, 2422), 50, (0, 255, 0), -1)
cv2.imwrite("path_to_write/img_test.png", im)
```

I would like to specify the center coordinates and the length of the square.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to overcome like below... a simple mathematics can help it seems. I post it here if someone else face this issue. If we know the center `(x,y)` & the length of the square.. we can compute the corners like below.

[image]

From this I can use;

```
cv2.rectangle(im, (x-1, y+1), (x+1, y-1), (255, 255, 255), 2)
```